# How is this get evaluated? (Crime)(getListAdapter()).getItem(position)

Tags: java, android

My Java is quite a bit rusty and I am currently learning Android. I encountered this particular line from the book I am reading:

```
(Crime)(getListAdapter()).getItem(position).
```

From what I understand is that this will convert the returned item (`Object` type) from `getItem()` to `Crime`. The question here is why is `(getListAdapter())` enclosed in parenthesis? Is there a meaning on that expression? Is this the same as (Crime) getListAdapter().getItem(position)? I knew that is not just Java but I am perplexed when I encountered this.

At this point I am confuse on the semantics of this kind of expression `z = (x)(y).`

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's being used to allow the cast to complete without starting a new expression. That allows the subsequent expression of `getItem(position)` to be on a `Crime`. It is equivalent to something like

```
Crime c = (Crime) getListAdapter(); // <-- parenthesis not needed
c.getItem(position); // <--  on the Crime
```

Answer (score 1):

`(Crime)(getListAdapter()).getItem(position)` is the same thing as `(Crime) getListAdapter().getItem(position)`

But if `getItem` method is defined in the Crime class and the type returned by `getListAdapter()` is a `java.lang.Object`, this code won't compile. In fact, the dot following the `getListAdapter()`will give access to all methods available in `java.lang.Object`only.

Maybe this line is wrong and the author wanted to write: `((Crime)getListAdapter()).getItem(position)`

In that case any dot following `((Crime)getListAdapter())` will give you access to all methods available in Crime class.